# Counting the number of $n = 10$ samples with $x$ common elements from two $N = 30$ sets with $10$ common elements

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I've been given the following assignment:

> Given the sets $N_1 = \{0,...,30\}$ and $N_2 = \{21,...,50\}$, what's the probability of observing $x$ common elements when taking an $n = 10$ sample from each?

This is what I came up with:

$$P(X = x) = \sum_{i=x}^{10}\binom{10}{i}\binom{20}{10-i}\binom{30-i}{10-x} / \binom{30}{10}^2$$

My reasoning is that, starting with either sample, we can first count the $\binom{10}{i}$ ways of selecting an element from the common set, then complete the sample with $10-i$ elements from the remaining $20$. Then, to ensure that there are $x$ common elements, for the second sample there are only $10 - x$ free elements which must come from the $30 - i$ which were not selected in the first sample.

I ran this through R and $\sum_{x=0}^{10}f(x) \neq 1$ so clearly there must be something wrong with my approach.

Comment: Should your sum run from $i=x+1$ to $10$?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see why. For $x = 0$ we could have the first sample lack any elements from the common set. Similarly, $x = 10$ is a possible outcome but having $i = 11$ would exclude it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you select the common $x$ elements out of the $10$ possibilities, the remaining $10-x$ could each be in one of the sets but not both.  If we let $y$ be the number of the elements in $[21,30]$ that are in the subset of $N_1$ but not in the subset of $N_2$  we get $$\frac{\sum_{y=0}^{10-x}{10 \choose x}{10-x \choose y}{20 \choose 10-x-y}{30-x-y \choose 10-x}}{{30 \choose 10}^2}$$  First we choose the common elements, then we choose the $y$ elements in $[21,30]$ that are in the subset of $N_1$ but not in the subset of $N_2$, then the remaining elements of the subset of $N_1$ then the remaining elements in the subset of $N_2$

Comment: Hi! It won't let me edit a single character, but your answer is almost correct. The last binomial term in the sum should be $\binom{30-x-y}{10-x}$, as $N_2$'s remaining elements must exclude the $y$ chosen for $N_1$. Thank you for the hint! I'll accept when the edit is made.

Comment: You are right and I have fixed it.  Thanks.  I won't use the old saw about leaving that to see if you were paying attention.

Comment: Oh boy, I (we?) may have incorrectly enumerated the elements here! Because it's a sampling (w/o replacement) procedure, order does matter and $\#\Omega = (30!/20!)^2$... or am I going crazy?

Comment: Yes, you are going crazy.  No, order doesn't matter.  You choose $10$ elements from $N_1$ without replacement.  There are $30 \choose 10$ ways to do that.  Then you choose $10$ elements from $N_2$ without replacement.  Again $30 \choose 10$ ways.  Then we look for matching numbers, but the matches do not influence the initial choice.

Comment: Bear with me - actually, isn't the answer contingent on the exact sampling procedure implemented? I know one normally would randomly choose from the list of subjects, but if instead we sequentially incorporated elements to the sample, then order would come into play. Another problem on sampling without replacement got me thinking about this the other day.

Comment: It only depends on the sampling procedure if that changes the probability of numbers being selected.  If I draw $10$ numbers out of $30$, each number has $1/3$ chance of being chosen, whether I look at them in order or wait until I have all of them before looking at any.  As long as each number has $1/3$ chance of being selected the above applies.